# pubspec.yaml has no lower-bound SDK constraint

Tags: flutter, sdk, flutter-web, lower-bound, flutter-pub

I was taking MDC101 flutter code lab. I cloned the starter project from the git repository as per the instructions but after clonning done, I executed `flutter pub get` and it gave me the following error.

```
pubspec.yaml has no lower-bound SDK constraint.
You should edit pubspec.yaml to contain an SDK constraint:
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.10.0 <3.0.0'
```

Comment: Just add environment:
  sdk: '>=2.10.0 <3.0.0' to top of dependencies : in pubspec.yaml

Comment: I have added environment:
  sdk: '>=2.10.0 <3.0.0' this line to bottom of pubspec.yaml and issue resolved

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the error instructions I added the following in my `pubspec.yaml`

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.10.0 <3.0.0'
```

And then I executed `flutter pub get` and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 38):

If you received this error even when your pubspec.yaml file contained the correct sdk line, *be sure to check subfolders in your main folder*. This was noted to happen while doing a `flutter packages get` from the font_awesome_flutter package. The reason was that even though the main pubspec.yaml contained the correct line, there was an offending `example/pubspec.yaml`. Add the lines to that file:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

[Referenced issue.](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/font_awesome_flutter/issues/153)

Comment: This is one of the problems. Should really be the accepted answer.

Comment: In my case the problem was not related to "font_awesome_flutter" but was a folder "example" from "OneSignal-Flutter-SDK\example" which contained the offending pubspec.yaml.

Comment: Tip: There are two pubspec.yaml files inside a flutter project, one is in the" root "folder, the other is inside" example/ "folder. We have to add this line to both two files.

Comment: where is the example/ folder?

Answer (score 3):

> As of Dart 2.12, omitting the SDK constraint is an error. When the pubspec has no SDK constraint, pub get fails with a message like the following:

```
pubspec.yaml has no lower-bound SDK constraint.
You should edit pubspec.yaml to contain an SDK constraint:
(...)
```

> For example, the following constraint says that this package works with any Dart SDK that’s version 2.10.0 or higher:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.10.0 <3.0.0'
```

For more information you can check the [docs](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#sdk-constraints)

Answer (score 0):

Check your flutter channel with command line :

`flutter channel`

if it is in master channel then switch to stable channel with :

`flutter channel stable`

Answer (score 0):

open the project with lower sdk version and new flutter project
copy the start code from the sdk to your new(deleting the startup code)
move the asset fold from lower sdk project to new projec, droping it on the new project name
open directory of new project delete the mipmap files from app>main>res and move
put the ones from the lower sdk
do same for iso>Runner>Assets.xcassets

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add the `environment: sdk: '>=2.10.0 <3.0.0'` to the pubspec.yaml file And press 'ctrl + s' then run the command `flutter pub get`.

Comment: Explain your answer for better understanding.